# Cant access images one directory back

Tags: linux, directory, absolute-path

I am using linux server and I am using absolute path for files which is stored in a "constant"

File path is

```
/home1/mousi1/public_html/xyz/data/1465221530.png
```

Image is loading when I access file which is on home directory like

```
/home1/mousi1/public_html/xyz/file.php
```

but when I try

```
/home1/mousi1/public_html/xyz/subdirectory/file.php
```

Path is still

```
/home1/mousi1/public_html/xyz/data/1465221530.png
```

but image is not showing I am wondering why is it?

What is wrong?

Comment: I think this question is better asked on Server Fault.

Comment: Ask on Server Fault or unix.stackexchange, but I suspect the issue will boil down to a setting in `/etc/php/php.ini` involving either `open_basedir` or `include_path`